# .NET C# autoreply

Tags: c#, .net, email

I have a form and I want to send an email reply to the sender after they have sent there message. Something like "Thank you for sending your message. We are currently going through all replies and will be in touch. Here is some further information that will be of help..."

This is the code that I have to send the form and works perfectly...

Any help much appreciated! Thanks.

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Form["T_NAME"].ToString() == "")
        {
            Literal1.Text = @"<span class=""error"">* Please enter your name</span>";
            ImageButton1.Focus();
            return;
        }
  if (Request.Form["T_ADD1"].ToString() == "")
        {
            Literal1.Text = @"<span class=""error"">* Please enter your address</span>";
            ImageButton1.Focus();
            return;
        }
        if (Request.Form["T_TEL"].ToString() == "")
        {
            Literal1.Text = @"<span class=""error"">* Please enter a telephone number</span>";
            ImageButton1.Focus();
            return;
        }
        if (Request.Form["T_EMAIL"].ToString() == "" || !clsCommon.IsValidEmailAddress(Request.Form["T_EMAIL"].ToString()))
        {
            Literal1.Text = @"<span class=""error"">* Please enter a valid email address</span>";
            ImageButton1.Focus();
            return;
        }
        if (Request.Form["T_DOB"].ToString() == "")
        {
            Literal1.Text = @"<span class=""error"">* Please enter your DOB</span>";
            ImageButton1.Focus();
            return;
        }


        string sFrom = Request.Form["T_EMAIL"].ToString();
        string sTo = "info@website.com";
        string sSubject = "Enquiry from the MakeUp Dept";
        string sBody = "The following enquiry was submitted from the website:" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Name: " + Request.Form["T_NAME"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
      "Address: " + Request.Form["T_ADD1"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
      "Address: " + Request.Form["T_ADD2"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Telephone: " + Request.Form["T_TEL"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                        "DOB: " + Request.Form["T_DOB"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Email: " + Request.Form["T_EMAIL"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                        "Course Interest: " + Request.Form["T_MSG"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
      "Make Up experience: " + Request.Form["T_EXP"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;


        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(sFrom, sTo, sSubject, sBody);
  SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("relay.website.com");
        //SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("localhost");
        smtp.Send(msg);

        Response.Redirect("apply-thank-you.htm");

    }
```

Comment: you say it works perfectly... what is the question?

Comment: I think he's saying "Here's the code we have that sends us the customer's message; how do I extend it to send them a message back too?" Which isn't that hard - have you tried copy/pasting the email code and changing the addresses?? Or reading up on the MailMessage class?

Comment: Probably the problem is that the mail isn't sent? But if you don't state your question, people will downvote you.

Comment: The question is there but hidden: `I want to send an email reply to the sender after they have sent (editor: posted) their message`

Comment: Not an answer to your question, I know, but: Do you know about [validators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z2h4sw.aspx)? With them you can have a client side check instead of those Request.Form["T_NAME"].ToString()=="" lines. Add a [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) to your page in the spot where you want the error message to appear, and let the `ControlToValidate` property point to the "T_NAME" control. Don't forget to check `Page.IsValid` in your click-handler.

Comment: The script sends the form to info@website.com. What I need is for the script to send an email to the person who inoput their email address in the form in the T_EMAIL input.

Answer (score 2):

You have the code there already to send the enquiry email, duplicate that swapping the To and From values and substitute your *Thank you* message in the Subject and Body fields. Thus (assuming that this code follows your existing email sending code):

```
    string ThanksFrom = "info@website.com";
    string ThanksTo = Request.Form["T_EMAIL"].ToString();
    string ThanksSubject = "Thank you for your enquiry";
    string ThanksBody = "Thank you for sending your message. We are currently going through all replies and will be in touch. Here is some further information that will be of help...";


    MailMessage ThanksMsg = new MailMessage(ThanksFrom, ThanksTo, ThanksSubject, ThanksBody);
    smtp.Send(ThanksMsg);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sSubject =  "Thank you dear friend!"
sBody = @"Hello our beloved customer!

We've received your message and We'll be back!";


MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(sTo, sFrom, sSubject, sBody);
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("relay.website.com");
smtp.Send(msg);
```